# User space application for CIFS

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I need to mount my windows share on linux machine which does not have CIFS kernel module. Is there any user space application available equivalent to CIFS kernel module?  Or is there simply anyway I can mount my shares on linux machines without CIFS ?

Comment: Does it have the FUSE kernel module?

Comment: no it does not have FUSE as well..

Comment: Then you could use smbclient, but that will not allow you to mount a remote share.

Answer (score 2):

There used to be `smbmount` and `smbfs`, but both seem to be more shipped with recent Linux distributions. They may still be available on older distributions. There are also `smbnetfuse` and `fusesmb` which both seem to offer a whole network of SMB servers on a single mountpoint. (I've tried `fusesmb` once but didn't get it to work.)

Besides the already mentioned GVFS, KIO and smbclient, there are also two more "browser" like tools for browsing SMB shares: `smb4k` (advanced share browser for KDE) and `smbc` (curses based SMB network browser).

Answer (score 1):

If you need it to be accessible as a regular filesystem, then it *must* be mounted – whether via cifs.ko or via FUSE – there's no good way around that.

Though, GNOME, Xfce or KDE programs have their own virtual filesystem layers, called Gvfs and KIO respectively. Both allow you to access `smb://server/share/...` within the program, as long as the needed clients (gvfs-smb) are installed.

(In theory, it would be possible to craft something similar which could be loaded into any program. But I haven't seen any attempts to do so; I guess it's sort of a waste of time given the existence of FUSE.)

Finally, if you only need to transfer a few files, you could use the ftp-like `smbclient` tool.